# Is it possible to change the theme for a Google Apps e-mail account?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

I like the way I can choose a theme in regular gmail, but I don't seem to find the option for my GoogleApps account. Is is possible to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is strange.

I never set my domain to use other language than English-USA.  The strangest thing, is, I didn't do anything and after a few days the tab "Themes" was available in Settings/Themes.

I wonder if reviewing my configuration somehow triggered "something"

:-/ I guess I'll never know.

Thank you all +1 to everyone :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm seeing this setting in `Settings -> Themes`. If it's not appearing for you, it might be because of [the Google Apps next-generation setting](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=52973) (which is avaliable in US English only).

Comment: My GApps is configured as UK and I get themes!

Answer (score 3):

This should be possible, but may be disabled by your administrator. We use Gmail/Google Apps at work, and I believe the administrators only allowed themes a month before it was released to our organization.

If themes were enabled, you would see them under the "Settings > Themes" menu. I can see that option from my Google Apps account.

The list at [Google Help](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=175121) (scroll down to "Features and Branding") shows that Themes are available for Google Apps.

Answer (score 1):

It must be enabled by your administrator. Specifically, it only appears if the administrator enables Gmail Labs.